# Access Denied & Unable to Change Attribute "pagefile.sys"

Tags: operating-system, pagefile

Using C-Cleaner to Analyze Disk C `" Win "`
it said that Sys File "pagefile.sys" is allocating 3.2 GB at`C:\`
[C-Cleaner pagefile.sys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXdPo.jpg)
The Problem is When i Open `C:\` , I can't see the File with `"Show hidden File "`
When Trying to change Attribute by Command `Atrrib -h -r -s *.*`, 
it says   [Command Attrib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUbz3.jpg)

So MY Question is
1) How `C-Cleaner` Could See `pafefile.sys` while I Couldn't with Administrative privileges
2) How Can i overcome `Access Denied & Unable to change Attribute` Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) How C-Cleaner Could See pafefile.sys while I Couldn't with Administrative privileges

You can easily view PAGEFILE.SYS by doing DIR/A.

> 2) How Can i overcome Access Denied & Unable to change Attribute Problem

The operating system is not going to allow you to muck with the page file directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I changed the owner to "everyone" for all items on c: and I also granted Full Access to "everyone" for all Items of c: and I tried each item on c: to be visible by
attrib /S -r -s -h *.*
But pagefile.sys and hiberfil.sys keep being invisible.
There is some hidden mechanism in Windows that keeps annoying you when you try to be aware of your partition image sizes.
In other word: when I open c:\ in explorer i need to see at a glance if there is large junk on the partition I am going to image.